# Service outage - BigQuery for import

Tags: google-bigquery

We just noticed that our imports for [BigQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigQuery) is failing with following message:

```
"status": {
    "state": "DONE",
    "errorResult": {
        "reason": "internalError",
        "message": "Unexpected. Please try again."
    },
    "errors": [
    {
        "reason": "internalError",
        "message": "Unexpected. Please try again."
    }
    ]
},
```

This has been happening now for over one hour. It started at 2:30 p.m. [PST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone). The console is reporting no known issues.

When will the service be back up?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized to a specific temporary product failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We switched our primary datacenter this afternoon and some metadata was messed up. The issue should be resolved as of 17:30 PST. We're conducting an internal postmortem.

Comment: First job that failed job_a9d677c487b34a408a015b070db8fe52. last one we tried: job_da1f6749c06840178b83c022f0e29a44. No software updates were done at our end. Let us know what you find.

Comment: last job was submitted at 4:32 pm PST. We have stopped our process and will turn it on when we have confirmation.

Comment: I'm also getting this error: job_6e81848d310145c2b71994cd6f3dfdfb was a recent attempt. Been getting this for over an hour now.

Comment: Updated my response with outage information.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! Everything back to normal now. I remember this happened once before. We are all caught up but will be good to have some notification, this way we can act at our end.